# Converting gnuplot color map to matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot

I am trying to port some plotting code from gnuplot to matplotlib and am struggling with porting a discontinuous color map that is specified by color names. **Any suggestions on how to do this in matplotlib?**

```
# Establish a 3-section color palette with lower 1/4 in the blues, 
# and middle 1/2 light green to yellow, and top 1/4 reds
set palette defined (0 'dark-blue', 0.5 'light-blue', \\
                     0.5 'light-green', 1 'green', 1.5 'yellow', \\
                     1.5 'red', 2 'dark-red')
# Establish that the palette range, such that the middle green range corresponds
# to 0.95 to 1.05
set cbrange [0.9:1.1]
```

[image: Desired colorbar]

Comment: I fear there is no 1:1 translation to matplotlib. Have a look at cdicts and `LinearSegmentedColormap`, but there you have to work with RGB values (and I have to admit, its not strait-forward to understand those cdicts), see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524471/custom-colormap-in-python and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bart's function is very nice. However, if you want to make the colormap yourself, you can define a colormap like this using a dictionary in the way it is done in the [`custom_cmap` example from the mpl website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html).

Here's an example that's pretty close to your colormap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

cdict = {'red':   ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),   # From 0 to 0.25, we fade the red and green channels
                   (0.25, 0.5, 0.5),   # up a little, to make the blue a bit more grey

                   (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),   # From 0.25 to 0.75, we fade red from 0.5 to 1
                   (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),   # to fade from green to yellow

                   (1.0,  0.5, 0.5)),  # From 0.75 to 1.0, we bring the red down from 1
                                       # to 0.5, to go from bright to dark red

         'green': ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),   # From 0 to 0.25, we fade the red and green channels
                   (0.25, 0.6, 0.6),   # up a little, to make the blue a bit more grey

                   (0.25, 1.0, 1.0),   # Green is 1 from 0.25 to 0.75 (we add red 
                   (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),   # to turn it from green to yellow)

                   (0.75, 0.0, 0.0),   # No green needed in the red upper quarter
                   (1.0,  0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0,  0.9, 0.9),   # Keep blue at 0.9 from 0 to 0.25, and adjust its
                   (0.25, 0.9, 0.9),   # tone using the green and red channels

                   (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),   # No blue needed above 0.25
                   (1.0,  0.0, 0.0))

             }

cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('BuGnYlRd',cdict)

data = 0.9 + (np.random.rand(8,8) * 0.2)  # Data in range 0.9 to 1.1

p=plt.imshow(data,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap,vmin=0.9,vmax=1.1)

plt.colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed very close. Is it possible to scale this active range to apply from 0.9 to 1.1 rather than 0 to 1?

Comment: Yep, that's easy enough, the colormap doesn't need to change. You can just change the range of the data and the `vmin` and `vmax` for the `imshow`. I'll edit the answer to show you

Comment: Perfect, and nice job explaining the rather tricky per color channel color map syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I've used this script for years, can't really remember how or where I got it (*edit*: after some searching, [this](http://depts.washington.edu/clawpack/clawpack-4.6.3/python/pyclaw/plotters/colormaps.py) seems to be the source, but it requires some minor changes for Python3), but it has helped me a lot in quickly creating custom color maps. It allows you to simply specify a dictionary with locations (`0..1`) and colors, and creates a linear color map out of that; e.g. `make_colormap({0:'w',1:'k'})` creates a linear color map going from white to black.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

def make_colormap(colors):
    from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ColorConverter
    from numpy import sort

    z  = np.array(sorted(colors.keys()))
    n  = len(z)
    z1 = min(z)
    zn = max(z)
    x0 = (z - z1) / (zn - z1)

    CC = ColorConverter()
    R = []
    G = []
    B = []
    for i in range(n):
        Ci = colors[z[i]]      
        if type(Ci) == str:
            RGB = CC.to_rgb(Ci)
        else:
            RGB = Ci
        R.append(RGB[0])
        G.append(RGB[1])
        B.append(RGB[2])

    cmap_dict = {}
    cmap_dict['red']   = [(x0[i],R[i],R[i]) for i in range(len(R))]
    cmap_dict['green'] = [(x0[i],G[i],G[i]) for i in range(len(G))]
    cmap_dict['blue']  = [(x0[i],B[i],B[i]) for i in range(len(B))]
    mymap = LinearSegmentedColormap('mymap',cmap_dict)
    return mymap

test1 = make_colormap({0.:'#40004b',0.5:'#ffffff',1.:'#00441b'})
test2 = make_colormap({0.:'b',0.25:'w',0.251:'g',0.75:'y',0.751:'r',1:'k'})

data = np.random.random((10,10))

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=test1) 
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(122)
pl.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=test2) 
pl.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. The function helps hide the intricacies of specifying the color channels independently.  Is it possible to scale the active range to apply from 0.9 to 1.1 rather than 0 to 1? And would it work to specify duplicate values as in `make_colormap({0:'w',0.5:'k', 0.5:'r', 1:'b'})`?

Comment: For the range `0.9--1.1`, see Toms answer (the same applies here). Duplicate values don't work at the moment (I just tested); I would use the pragmatic approach and simply use `({0:'w',0.5:'k', 0.500000000001:'r', 1:'b'})`, but you could change the function and do this automatically for duplicate values.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Too bad nothing like this is built-in to matplotlib.The native per channel color map syntax is non-intuitive.